# and I read the one on physics

Tags: meaning, adjectives, pronouns, ellipsis

a. He read the boring article on biology and I read the one on physics.

Was the article I read necessarily boring?

---

b. He read the boring articles on biology and I read those on physics.

Were the articles I read necessarily boring?

---

c. I read the long novel about the Middle Ages and the one about time travel.

Was the novel about time travel necessarily long?

---

d. I read the long novels about the Middle Ages and those about time travel.

Were the novels about time travel necessarily long?

Answer (score 2):

No, not necessarily, in all cases.  It would be possible to say:

> He read the boring article on biology and I read the interesting one on physics.

If "boring" necessarily applied to the physics article too, this would be contradictory  ("the boring interesting one").  But it isn't.

On the other hand context may suggest that both articles are indeed boring. You don't need to repeat the word if your opinion on the article is clear from context or from non-verbal clues.